# xpath expression for clicking link if unique identifier is in sibling element

Tags: java, selenium

What's the correct xpath for clicking link (< a >) if the unique identifier ("Column3") is in parallel tag?

```
<th ...>
<th ...>
<th>
    <span>Column3</span>
    <a onClick="removeColumn(column)">...</a>
</th>
```

Comment: //span[text()='Column3']../a[1]

Comment: Thanks...//span[text()='Column3']/../a[1] - worked!

Comment: You can also simply locate it using `By.linkText("your link text")`...

Answer (score 1):

```
//span[text()='Column3']/following-sibling::a[1]
```

- first link that follows the span with text "Column3" within the same parent.